# How is this a "non-homogenous Poisson process"

Tags: poisson-process

The question is:
The number of car accidents an insured person faces depends on their experience. The rate at which Liam will have car accidents is given by:
$$R(e) = \frac{(e+0.5)^{-2}}{200},$$
where $e$ is the experience in years.

I am required to find probabilities related to this, but the solution starts out with:
The rate at which Liam will have a car accident is a non-homogenous (continuous time) Poisson process.
How is this in any way a Poisson process? Like, what does the function have to do with it? Is this just assumed?

Comment: Indeed the formulation is sloppy. Rather, one should say that *the set of times when Liam has a car accident is a non-homogenous Poisson process*.